# Minecraft - Commandblocks With No Name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

By using command blocks, is there a way to `/say` without it outputting

```
[CommandBlocks Name]/Say Command
```

Basically Is there a way to get command blocks to not have a name?

So instead of

```
[CommandBlocks Name]/Say Command
```

It would just be

```
/Say Command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/tellraw @a "Text"
```

Using tellraw, you can also change the color and style of the text, as well as allow it to execute commands when clicked. See [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-7-1-8-raw-json-text-examples-for-tellraw-title) for more details.

Comment: YES! This was exactly what i wanted, I knew there was a way, but I had no idea how to do this,
Thanks